# Integrating XAML apps in Unity projects

Tags: xaml, unity-game-engine, uwp

I've been developing a Unity3D project with Hololens using the Mixed Reality Toolkit, running smoothly with now problems. I'm trying now to create a Single-SignOn capability in the project - a Web Account Manager - by following this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-account-manager), which uses XAML's to display and use the information of a AccountSettingsPane.

As a beginner of XAML and UWP development, I'm having a problem in how to integrate this with Unity. I tried turning the Account project into a plugin but no success because it doesn't seems to recognize the XAML code (and I've been able to create other UWP plugins previously). But I don't even know if this is the correct course of action.

I've search for resolutions but the only thing I find is XAML's running Unity apps and I'm looking for otherwise. I also tried to check if the plugin had any problem but I don't have a way to know since it doesn't returns errors, it simply doesn't do anything.

Did anyone tried to integrate a XAML project with Unity successfully or if it is possible at all? Or point me in the right direction since I feel a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post that describes a similar authentication process, where you jump out of the 3D Unity app to a browser to complete the authentication process and than go back to Unity: https://peted.azurewebsites.net/microsoft-graph-auth-on-hololens/

The sample linked at the bottom was changed to a different auth method which might not be available for your thing, but you can just go back to the old state of the repo by checking out an older commit: https://github.com/peted70/msal-hololens